# Simperium Received Error [Client Error : 412] for object with key []

Tags: ios, objective-c, simperium

Hello Simperium users,

what does this error mean / how to fix this ?

thanks 
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Error 412 means that the client sent a diff that caused no changes backend side. You can learn more about the Simperium protocol here:

https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-protocol/blob/master/SYNCING.md

Would it be possible to get the log that caused that error to show up?. 
(+ May i ask you which Simperium version you're currently using? You can find that in the SPEnvironment class, constant SPLibraryVersion).

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be working okay now, I'll close this request. Thanks for your advice ;-)

Comment: Glad to hear that Frank!